# mod_rewrite to avoid duplicate content after clean urls

Tags: mod-rewrite, duplicates, http-status-code-404

I have the typical mod_rewrite rules to make urls prettier

```
RewriteRule ^most-viewed-([0-9]+)$ index.php?views=$1
```

But somehow, Google managed to get the index.php?views= version too, so now, in google search results both results show, the one with the mod_rewrite url, and the "regular" one.

This is bad for seo because of dupliate content, and I know I can use canonical tag, but I would prefer to show a 404 when index.php is accessed without being called by the rewrite rule.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicated search results because of mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925490/duplicated-search-results-because-of-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

You should check your page on your website, somewhere you let google find the index.php?views=.

You could take some measure against that :

- Check your log to see exactly what Google crawler do.

  - If there is only few page, block403 or redirect301 them manually in your htaccess.
  - If there is a lot of page, block403 or redirect301 them with advanced regex rules to matche every case you've seen in your htaccess.
- Place Canonical rules on your duplicate page.
- Forbid the access to that page with your robots.txt.
- Forbid the crawl on the "views" parameter on webmastertools.
- Check your log after every of these step are done to see exactly what Google crawler still do.